# What is the term for replacing a name or brand with a funny pejorative / sardonicism?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, pejorative-language, linguistics

What is the term for when one replaces a well-known name [(Proper) noun, company, brand, etc.] with one that tries to be funny yet pejoratively descriptive, different but similar enough that one's audience can likely understand the replacement?

For example: Whole Foods ===> Whole Paycheck; Comcast ==> Scumcast; Starbucks ==> Charbucks; Kinko's == Stinko's; eBay ==> Evil Bay

I tend to use sobriquet don't believe this explicitly implies funny as well as insulting. Moniker again is close but not specific to the above description.

There is a similar question which proposes tortonym and malapropsim, but it does not seem to settle the argument definitively: [Is there a term for pejorative parody names of people or places?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54289/is-there-a-term-for-pejorative-parody-names-of-people-or-places)

Another answer here proposes dysphemism, but to me it isn't a full fit:
[What do you call it when a name/word is better known by a pejorative?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60494/what-do-you-call-it-when-a-name-word-is-better-known-by-a-pejorative) because it doesn't cover the humor aspect.

Comment: [***Dysphemism***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysphemism) comes close. For the "humor aspect", I'd just go for *amusing dysphemism* or *puerile dysphemism*, depending on how you see it.

Comment: I might call that an ***intentional malapropism***

Comment: How is this question different from the first one you linked to?

Answer (score 6):

The term *[dysphemism](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dysphemism)* is appropriate:

> noun
>
> A derogatory or ***unpleasant*** term used ***instead*** of a ***pleasant*** or neutral one. The opposite of euphemism.
>
> *ODO, **emphasis** mine*

Brands are designed to generate pleasant feelings in the marketplace, but these monikers are proffered to ***defame*** the brand with a sense of contempt, as the specific meanings of the prefix and root imply:

> *[dys](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dys-)*- = bad, ill, difficult
>   *[pheme](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=dysphemism&searchmode=none)* = fame
>   [-*ism*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-ism) = noun form of state, quality, action or result

---

If the existing word seems too serious for this specialized insult veiled in "humor", I can highly recommend the [portmanteau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) neologism ***slurbriquet***.

Combining *[slur](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/slur)*:

> 3 chiefly US Make damaging or insulting ***insinuations*** or allegations
>   about:
>
> *ODO, **emphasis** mine*

and *[sobriquet](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sobriquet)*:

> noun
>
> A person’s nickname:
>
> *ODO*

*Comcast customers have have baptized their cable provider with an effective **slurbriquet**: Scumcast*